# How to convert a string containing an array value to a PHP array?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, curl

I have a string that contains an array like:

```
$tarray = Array ( [gt_ref_id] => 36493115 [tender_notice_type] => [organisation_name] => ROSALES WATER DISTRICT [address] => No. 5 Bonifacio Street [address2] => [contact_person] => [tender_notice_no] => ROSALWD 2016-011-0144(Ref: 4206661)
)
```

but I want to access the value of this array like:

```
echo "ref id = ".$tarray['gt_ref_id'];
```

It should output like:

```
ref id = 36493115
```

but I can't because it's a string. I could if it was an array.

How can I convert the string to a proper PHP array?

Comment: Where did you get this string?

Comment: why are you storing array representation as string ? use serialize or json_encode instead.

Comment: I just get this string from an link which i read by the php function file_get_contents which provide me an array. Bug because of this function i got that array as string.

Comment: So tell us how you generate that file you are reading. Thats where the issue is

Comment: actually i am working on a codeigniter project and i got that string from a link by $data['detail'] = file_get_contents("http://infostores.biz/globaltenders/awlog_array.php?user=****&pass=****&id=789029");

Comment: @Steve i can't use require because these both projects are on different servers.

Comment: Yep figured that out after your last comment so deleted mine. Looks like the data you are receiving data isn't formatted properly. If you are restricted to getting the data this way, Regex will help you extract the information.

Comment: send it as json (`json_encode`) and then do `json_decode($data, true);` on the value you get from `file_get_contents`

Comment: I would _bet the farm_ that is not how they are returning that data. Do a `print_r($data['detail']);` So we can see what is **really** being returned from that call

Comment: @RiggsFolly The link infostores.biz/globaltenders/awlog_array.‌​php?user=****&pass=*‌​***&id=789029 returns and array which i cant get without using file_get_contents(). But beacause of using this function it convert this array into string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want store a php array on you database you can try with `json_encode` or `serialize`, and when you would need retrive data from you database, you can use `json_decode` or `unserialize`.

**Using `JSON`**

Examples(store as json):

```
$myArray = array('name' => 'Jack', 'lastname' => 'Smith', 24);
$toStore = json_encode($myArray); // return a string: {"name":"Jack","lastname":"Smith","0":24}

mysqli_query($link,
    'INSERT INTO myTable (data)
    VALUES ("' . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $toStore) . '")'
);
```

Examples(retrieved from json):

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT FROM MyTable WHERE id = ...');
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$row = json_decode($row); // return a array: array('name' => 'Jack', 'lastname' => 'Smith', 24)
```

**Using `serialize`**

Example(store serialized):
    $myArray = array('name' => 'Jack', 'lastname' => 'Smith', 24);
    $toStore = serialize($myArray); // return a string: a:3:{s:4:"name";s:4:"Jack";s:8:"lastname";s:5:"Smith";i:0;i:24;}

```
mysqli_query($link,
    'INSERT INTO myTable (data)
    VALUES ("' . mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $toStore) . '")'
);
```

Examples(retrieve serialized):

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT FROM MyTable WHERE id = ...');
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
$row = unserialize($row); // return a array: array('name' => 'Jack', 'lastname' => 'Smith', 24)
```

**After :**

if you need access to you data from converted array, you can call like:

```
$row['name'] // return "Jack"
```

**Another ways**

*Regexp:*

You can try use regexp, but this not the best way because sometime is too slow to process data, and maybe, if you don't know security aspects, this definitely not is the best way.

*Tokenizer:*

You can try create you own token processor, like template engine, but this is the most large way...

**Learn more about the functions:**

- [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) API
- [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) API
- [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) API
- [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) API

**Pros:**

1. Support multiple data-types: multidimentional `array`, `object`,
   `integer`, `float`, `string`, and many more data except `resource`.
2. Native support for `serialize` and `unserialize` since PHP4.
3. Native support for `json_encode` and `json_decode` since PHP 5.2.0
4. Fast and secure encode and decode.

Comment: hey @Olaf Erlandsen thanks... **json_decode** worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Olaf Erlandsen you should probably store your array in another format -- serialized or as a json dump. I'd prefer the latter.

However, chances are that you're not the one generating this (rather odd) string. It may be provided by someone else. In that case you could use a regular expression (RegEx) to extract the keys and values of the array.

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to match them and then loop over the matches to join them into an array. I find it easier to loop over the results when the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag is set.

**Example code:**

```
$string = "Array ( [gt_ref_id] => 36493115 [tender_notice_type] => hiha [organisation_name] => ROSALES WATER DISTRICT [address] => No. 5 Bonifacio Street [address2] => [contact_person] => [tender_notice_no] => ROSALWD 2016-011-0144(Ref: 4206661))";
$string = substr( $string, 8 ); # Strip Array ( , from beginning of string.
$string = substr( $string, 0, - 1 ); # Strip last ) from string.

preg_match_all( "/\[(.*?)\] => ([^\[]*)/", $string, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER );

foreach ( $matches as $match ) {
    $tarray[ $match[1] ] = substr( $match[2], 0, - 1 );
    # Note that $match[2] contains a trailing white-space, stripping it with substr().
    # On another note, you should probably check whether $match[2] has any content.
}

var_dump($tarray);
```

I put the [pattern](https://regex101.com/r/ECbI2l/1) up on regex101, that'll probably make things clearer if you're new to these *patterns*.

**Note:** I'm not exactly a RegEx-genious, maybe someone can check the pattern I provided.

Comment: this exampel don't support multidimentional arrays.

Comment: whats happend if you store array like `['a'=>1, 'b'=>2]`?

Comment: This example indeed doesn't support multidimensional arrays, it would also fail if one of the values contains a `[ `. Based on OP's question I don't think those two limitations will be a problem.